# Php cookie read/write sequence

Tags: php, select, cookies, submit

I am submiting a php to itself through a dropdown that changes the page's interface language.
While doing that I am updating a cookie that stores the **HTML body TAG direction: rtl OR ltr**.

So while the **HTML SELECT** tag submits its value through a **FORM onChage() func call** to a JavaScript, and the Javascript reloads the *PHP* page, at the head of the *php* page there is an *INCLUDE* for the translation PHP page and when the page is rewritten the direction of the *BODY TAG* is to be updated according to language.

Well, this actually reads the cookie **BODY TAG DIR** only the second time the language is changed, hence, body directions are not always correct.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
include '../dbc.php';
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
include './includes/getranslation.php';
?>
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
function reload(form) {
var val=form.langselector.options[form.langselector.options.selectedIndex].value;
SetCookie( 'lang', '' + val);
self.location='login.php';
}
</SCRIPT>

</head>
<body dir='<?php echo $_COOKIE['langdir']; ?>'>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" class="main">
        <tr> <?php if ($_COOKIE["langdir"] == 'ltr') {
            $ddlangalignleftTD = 'right';
            $ddlandalignrightTD = 'left';
            } else {
            $ddlangalignleftTD = 'left';
            $ddlandalignrightTD = 'right';
            }
            ?>
            <td width="50%" align="<?php echo $ddlangalignleftTD; ?>" valign="center">
                <?php echo $headingNamesArr['select_lang']; ?>:
            </td>
            <td width="50%" align="<?php echo $ddlandalignrightTD; ?>" valign="center">
                <form method="post" name="langselectorfrm" action="login.php">
                    <select name="langselector" onchange="reload(this.form)">
                        <?php echo '<option value= ''</option>';
                        ?>
                    </select> 
                </form>
```

**I WOULD LIKE TO KNOW WHY IT DOES NOT READ THE UPDATED COOKIE, ONLY AFTER THE SECOND TIME IT IS SUBMITTED?**

Hope you understand....

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is only seen the second time the page loads. because on the first load the cookie **does not exists** yet.

Comment: How come? what is the order of the page loading in relation with the cookie? is there a work around to have the cookie before the page starts loading? after all, its a file written to th hard disk....
Thanx.

Comment: Neal, I C your credit is quite high so I will ask: I have posted another question here (Still looking for this site's support...) and I keep on getting this messege:
Your question "Ubuntu Server static Route through ubuntu PC" was migrated to Super User.

What does that mean???

And another Q if I may: do I get a credit for every question? answer? what? what is the system here...

Before registering I found this site one of the most usefull ones for answers. Now that I am registered its harder to get answers...:-)
JadeYe

Comment: @Jadeye -- you can ask and see those types of questions on http://meta.stackoverflow.com